# Is $\{ \text{Lebesgue points} \} \subset \{x: |f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a locally Lebesgue integrable function $f$ on $\Bbb R^n$. Let $L_f$ be the set of [Lebesgue points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point)  of $f$. Then $(L_f)^c$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity#Function_space) of the $L^\infty$ norm, if $S$ is the set defined by
$$S=\{x: |f(x)| \leq \|f\|_\infty\},$$
then $S^c$ has Lebesgue measure zero, that is $|f(x)|\leq \|f\|_\infty$ a.e.

My question: Is $L_f = S$? Or at least is the inclusion $L_f \subset S$ true?

I know this question might look strange, but I'm reading an article and I think they're using this fact, but I'm not sure about that and I don't know how to prove it, maybe there's something about Lebesgue points that I'm ignoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If $\|f\|_\infty$ means $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}$ then its trivially true for some $f\in L^1_{loc}$ since this would be just a weird way to write $\{x:f(x)\le \infty\}$.)

If $x$ is a Lebesgue point, then by Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem,
$$ |f(x)| = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac1{|B_r|}\int_{B_r(x)}|f(y)|dy \le \lim_{r\to 0} \|f\|_{L^\infty(B_r(x))} \le \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)},$$
proving that $L_f \subset S$.

The opposite inclusion is false: let $f$ be the following particular representative of $1\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$,
$$ f(x)= \mathbf 1_{x\neq 0} .$$ Then it is easy to see that $x=0$ is not a Lebesgue point, but $0=f(0) \le \|f\|_{L^\infty} = 1$. So $0\in S \setminus L_f$.

Comment: Thanks. I think they're using that $\sup L_f = \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)}$ in the article, which I think is true by the definition of essential supremum, could you please confirm if that's true?

Comment: @Twink I guess it should be $\sup |f|(L_f)$ instead of $\sup L_f$. This is true, $\sup |f|(L_f) \le \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ is given by the above LDT argument, and the definition of essential supremum guarantees $\sup |f|(L_f) \ge \inf_{N \text{ null}} \sup_{\mathbb R^n\setminus N} |f(x)| =: \|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Comment: Sorry, yes, it would be $|f|$, in the article $f$ is nonnegative, that's why I forgot the absolute value. Thank you for confirming this :-)

Comment: @Twink well I was more worried about talking about the domain instead of the range, as $\sup L_f=\infty$  for any $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^1)$ (and doesn't quite make sense if the domain is higher dimensional). You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry again, I meant $\sup_{L_f} f = \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R^n)}$ in my first comment, and my function $f$ is nonnegative in $L_f$.